# Failure in starting puppetserver

Tags: puppet

When I try to start puppet on master server, it fails

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ sudo service puppetserver restart
   ...fail!
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$
```

ubuntu version 14.04. I am new to puppet, trying to see its benefit over ansible. I am ansible guy basically.I have just installed it. I am able to successfully start puppetagent on my agent machine

Comment: Check and provide the logs, particularly /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.log

Comment: Also what version and how did you install it?